# Remove beginning or trailing comma from delimited string

Tags: php, linux, awk, sed

This can be done with awk,sed,or PHP. I have comma delimited string of which I want remove a value.

```
mike,suzy,carter,jason

$remove_value = mike
sed 's/$remove_value//' file_with_delimited_string
```

This gives me ',suzy,carter,jason'

```
$remove_value = jason
sed 's/$remove_value//' file_with_delimited_string
```

This gives me 'mike,suzy,carter,'

How do I remove the errant comma regardless of the location of the value removed? This is a large file with many comma delimited strings. This change has to be for the current match only. I'm using PHP to edit a text file on a Linux server.

Comment: Use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) or [ltrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this simple way

```
sed "s/,\?$remove_value,\?//" FileName
```

If you test middle value you can use this way

```
sed "s/,$remove_value\|$remove_value,//" FileName
```

If you remove all value which are occurred in the line use `g`

```
sed "s/,$remove_value\|$remove_value,//g" FileName
```

**Example:**

```
remove_value='mike'
```

**Output:**

```
suzy,carter,jason
```

**Example:**

```
remove_value='suzy'
```

**Output:**

```
mike,carter,jason
```

**Example :**

```
remove_value='jason'
```

**Output:**

```
mike,suzy,carter
```

Comment: what if the `jason` present at the middle?

Comment: Oh wait...yeah if it's in the middle that won't work

Comment: @AvinashRaj, As per your input string my command will removed the first occurrence only .if you need to remove all occurrence use `g` flag for remove all occurrence.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -r "s/$remove_value,?//g; s/,$//" File
```

Comment: sorry, need to use double quotes!! i tested via commandline with mike, carter, etc...

Comment: class is not needed `[,]`, a simple `,` and none of the `g` are needed (one occurance in each case, at least the second if several same name could appear in the line)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: right! keeping the first 'g' for multiple occurence (generic)

Comment: you are welcome. You could also replace the `?` with `\{0,1\}` if `-r` is not available (like posix sed)

Answer (score 0):

This'll do the trick.

```
$remove_value = ltrim($remove_value, ',');
$remove_value = rtrim($remove_value, ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a wacky way to do it in php:

```
  $list  = 'mike,suzy,carter,jason';
  $list_array = explode(',' , $list);
  $goner = 'suzy';
  $goner_index = array_search($goner, $list_array);
  unset($list_array[$goner_index]);
  $list = implode(',', $list_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

In php through single regex.

```
$str = "jason,mike,jason,suzy,carter,jason";
$remove_value = "jason";
echo preg_replace('~,'.$remove_value.'(?=,|$)|^'.$remove_value.',~', "", $str);
```

Output:

```
mike,suzy,carter
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
$ for replace_string in mike suzy carter jason; 
    do awk -v s=$replace_string '{ sub("((,|^)"s")|("s"(,|$))","") }1' a.txt; 
  done

suzy,carter,jason
mike,carter,jason
mike,suzy,jason
mike,suzy,carter
```